# SVT-AV1 for real time transmission

Tags: c++, c

I have following Client-Server **Situation**:

Server:

- maintains multiple CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) frames (like a background webbrowser)
- those CEF frames deliver image data in irregular intervals - varying between 0-30fps

  if a video is played or a lot user interaction is going on it's 30fps - very rarely(!)

  usually no image data is delivered if nothing is happening - most of the time
- sending this data to the client - as is - puts too much weight on the network connection
- thus I use or would like to use SVT-AV1 encoding (latest releases are very performant)

Client:

- receives SVT-AV1 data, decodes and presents it (yes, SVT-AV1 contains a decoder)
- user interaction (mouse, keyboard) is transmitted to server CEF frames via another connection

**Problems**

1. SVT-AV1 seems to require a steady(!) stream of input frames.
2. It also seems to spit out encoded frames (packages) in long time intervals but I can only wait a few milliseconds or the lag makes it unusable.

**Questions**

1. Can anyone tell me how I have to tweak those SVT-AV1 encoder parameters so I reliably get an encoded packet after inserting new frame image data? (1 for 1)
2. Packets do not need to be/contain keyframes (except the first one of course).
3. Can anyone tell me how I have to tweak those SVT-AV1 decoder parameters so I reliably get a decoded frame after inserting a packet (1 for 1)

I use the SVT-AV1 library - not the executable - with a dangerous half knowledge.

Encoder Parameters: https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/master/Source/API/EbSvtAv1Enc.h?ref_type=heads#L217

Decoder Parameters: https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1/-/blob/master/Source/API/EbSvtAv1Dec.h?ref_type=heads#L56
Currently only max_picture_width, max_picture_height, max_bit_depth and max_color_format is set.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can't the AV1 codec efficiently compress a 30fps stream of a static picture?

Comment: I could do that of course. But the CPU would melt compressing that many streams at the same time in that case.
As said there could be a lot of CEF frames open and all be visible on the client side at the same time.